# Confused Why "control may reach end of non-void function"

Tags: c++

I wrote the following code to check the elements of a vector to see is they are equal. However, it is wrong for some reason and I cannot determine why. I do se that the "control may reach end of non-void function". Which doesn't make sense because I  don't see a point where that would occur.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Also, this is in xCode, more specifically, the program is written in C++.

```
bool equalElements(vector<string> fileExtensionsArray){
    for (int i=0; i<fileExtensionsArray.size(); i++){
    int j=i+1;
        if(fileExtensionsArray.at(i) == fileExtensionsArray.at(j)){
            return false;
        }
        else{
            return true;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: If `fileExtensionsArray` is empty, the body of the loop never runs, and thus `return` statements are not reached.

Comment: So, do I need to define the size of it in the header? Or, a better question would be: How would I go about solving this issue? @IgorTandetnik

Comment: You would decide what `equalElements` should return when called with an empty vector, and implement it accordingly. Further, you should also decide what to do with one-element vector; currently, you access an index out of bounds. Further still, as written, your function doesn't make much sense. You have a loop - but you always return on the very first iteration of the same. You only ever compare element 0 with element 1, and return based purely on that comparison. No other elements are looked at.

Comment: Your function copies the entire vector. Why not pass by const reference? If the vector is not empty, the function will return after only one iteration of the for loop.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

#### Case : `fileExtensionsArray` is empty.

If your `fileExtensionsArray` is an empty `std::vector`,

`fileExtensionsArray.size()` will be equal to `0`.

Hence the `for` loop will never be executed, hence there would be no `return` statements to be executed.

To fix this, you could simply add a `return false` below the end of the function definition.

```
bool equalElements(vector<string> fileExtensionsArray){
    for (int i=0; i<fileExtensionsArray.size(); i++){
    int j=i+1;
        if(fileExtensionsArray.at(i) == fileExtensionsArray.at(j)){
            return false;
        }
        else{
            return true;
        }
    }
return false; //Empty vectors are equal? Maybe not.
}
```

Answer (score 2):

What would happen if `fileExtensionsArray` is empty? The `for-loop` wouldn't execute and none of your `return` statements would be executed.

Answer (score 2):

Your function definition guaranteed a return value. If `fileExtensionsArray` is empty,   it is missing a return value in your function definition.